# R Linear programming

Tags: r, linear-programming

**Example 1.**
Use R, in similar way as above, to solve the following problem:
The Handy-Dandy Company makes three types of kitchen appliances (A, B and C).

To make each of
these appliance types, just two inputs are required - labour and materials. Each unit of A made requires
7 hours of labour and 4 Kg of materials; for each unit of B made the requirements are 3 hours of
labour and 4 Kg of materials, while for C the unit requirements are 6 hours of labour and 5 Kg of
material.

The company expects to make a profit of €40 for every unit of A sold, while the profit per
unit for B and C are €20 and €30 respectively. Given that the company has available to it 150 hours of
labour and 200 Kg of material each day, formulate this as a linear programming problem.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlVJ.png)

```
x1 <- Rglpk_read_file("F:\ \Linear_programming_R\\first.txt", type = "MathProg")

Rglpk_solve_LP(x1$objective, x1$constraints[[1]], x1$constraints[[2]], x1$constraints[[3]],
x1$bounds, x1$types, x1$maximum)
```

Can someone explain to me what 1,2,3 in brackets mean? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those access elements of a list; so `x1$constraints` is a list and `x1$constraints[[1]]` is the first component of that list.

The operator $ accesses a variable in an object (data.frame). Have a look at some tutorial about data types in R [for example here](http://www.homogenisation.org/admin/docs/Lists&DataFrames.pdf)